# Plot one part of a DataFrame independent of filter

Tags: python, altair

I would like to plot a part of my data frame depending on the value of a slider (i.e. the slider filters the rows that have a matching value in a certain column). Some rows lack a value in the column which is used for filtering. I would like these rows to always be shown in the plot - irrespective of the slider.

Here's some code for clarification. The column used for filtering is called `parameter` in this example.

```
In [1]:  import altair as alt
         import pandas as pd

In [2]:  df_with_parameter_col = pd.DataFrame(
             {
                 "x": [1, 1],
                 "y": [2, 3],
                 "parameter": [2, 3]
             }
         )

         df_without_parameter_col = pd.DataFrame(
             {
                 "x": [1],
                 "y": [1]
             }
         )

In [3]:  df = pd.concat([df_with_parameter_col,
                         df_without_parameter_col])
         df
Out [3]:        x   y   parameter
            0   1   2   2.0
            1   1   3   3.0
            0   1   1   NaN

In [4]:  slider_parameter = alt.binding_range(min=2, max=3, step=1, name="Parameter ")

         select_parameter = alt.selection_single(
             fields=["parameter"],
             bind={"parameter": slider_parameter},
             init={"parameter": 2},
             name="Slider"
         )

         chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
             y="y",
             x="x",
         ).add_selection(
             select_parameter
         ).transform_filter(
             select_parameter
         )
```

The data in the row with the missing value in the column `parameter` is never plotted. One way around this issue would be to duplicate this row *for every possible value* of the slider and change the NaN to a value that can match a slider's value. However, that would be very wasteful in terms of memory. Is there a nicer solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a slightly more sophisticated filter statement, using the [vega expression](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/) syntax:

```
slider_parameter = alt.binding_range(min=2, max=3, step=1, name="Parameter ")

select_parameter = alt.selection_single(
    fields=["parameter"],
    bind={"parameter": slider_parameter},
    init={"parameter": 2},
    name="Slider"  # Note: if this is changed, change the name below as well.
)

alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    y="y",
    x="x",
).add_selection(
    select_parameter
).transform_filter(
    # Note: "Slider" here matches the `name` specified for the selection.
    # Its attributes are drawn from the `fields` specified for the selection.
    "!isValid(datum.parameter) || (datum.parameter == Slider.parameter)"
)
```

[image]